# Создание Bitmap с большим размером

Tags: android, bitmap

C помощью

`createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)`

создается Bitmat на основе существующего. Проблема в том, что если в `width`, `height` указать размер больше за размер исходного Bitmap source, выбивает ошибку. Как это решить? Т.е создать `Bitmap` на основе существующего, только с большими `width`, `height`

Comment: а как вы себе это представляете? что должно быть за пределами старого битмапа? Или вы хотите растянуть?

Comment: растянуть.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе `Bitmap` есть статический метод `createScaledBitmap(oldBitmap, 120, 120, false)`, который и возвращает битмап с новыми шириной и высотой. [Ссылка](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean))

Comment: спасибо.........

Comment: @antonin14d, не за что, если ответ показался вам полезным - отметьте его как верный